Сокращение количества цифр после запятой в float на C++
Есть float, который имеет значение от 0.0 до 1.0, он приобретает значение 0.666666
Нужно сделать так чтобы после . было только 4 цифры, пробуя реализовать разные способы на VSCode, ничего не получается, что я пробовал:

через деления с умножением
через round и т.п.
через перевод через строку
через разбиение на массив чаров и перевод обратно
через функцию, которая разбивает число на целое и остаток

Все попытки заканчивались тем что float вспоминал свое старое значение и возвращался в исходное состояние

Может, вам надо выводить только четыре цифры (не числа!) после точки?...

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Float числа 0.6666 не существует! Введите его в верхней строчке: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html  Опишите реальную проблему, зачем вам понадобились такие действия. Скорее всего вам нужно то, что Harry написал

Исправил, немного некорректно написал, извините

Как бы, осталось только уточнить "чтобы после . было только 4 цифры", 4 цифры где? На экране или в файле, это одно, это просто. Или в переменной float, строго говоря, это невозможно, но можно как-то переформулировать задачу.

В самой переменной

@владуваров, внутренний формат самой переменной не предусматривает управление количеством десятичных цифр после запятой

Извините, я поторопился дать ответ, не выяснив до конца того, что же именно  Вам надо. А именно: число такими же первыми 4-я цифры десятичного представления, или число округлённое до 4-х цифр? Я дал ответ для последнего варианта, но сейчас добавил ещё и первый.

В самой переменной 'float' невозможно хранить, ни 0.666666, ни 0.6667 (или 0.6666 в зависимости от того, что назвать требуемыми 4-мя цифрами). Можно хранить, только ближайшие к ним числа.
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout.precision(numeric_limits<float>::max_digits10);

    float in = 0.666666f;

    cout << "Вход Согласно IEEE: " << in << '\n';
    cout << "Предыдущее и последующее float: "
         << nextafterf(in, 0.) << ", "
         << in << ", "
         << nextafterf(in, INFINITY) << "\n\n";

    float x = round(in*10000.)/10000.;

    cout << "Выход Согласно IEEE: " << x << '\n';
    cout << "Предыдущее и последующее float: "
         << nextafterf(x, 0.) << ", "
         << x << ", "
         << nextafterf(x, INFINITY) << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}

Печатает:
$ clang++ x666.cpp && ./a.out
Вход Согласно IEEE: 0.666665971
Предыдущее и последующее float: 0.666665912, 0.666665971, 0.666666031

Выход Согласно IEEE: 0.666700006
Предыдущее и последующее float: 0.666699946, 0.666700006, 0.666700065

И действительно, 0.666700006 ближе к 0.6667, чем 0.666699946.
P.S.
Строго говоря, в операции float x = round(in*10000.)/10000. есть одна маловероятная засада, in*10000. выполняется точно, round(...)/10000. вычисляется с округлением типа double, присвоение округляет результат до float, и при крайне неудачном сочетании этих округлений, можно получить не самое ближайшее значение float, а соседнее.
Т.е. такой код не следует использовать там, где нужна гарантированная точность, к примеру, при печати многозначных чисел и т.п.
Но в данном случае, нам повезло.
P.P.S.
С точки зрения математики, для понимания вышеприведённого кода, описания стандартной функции nextafterf() достаточно, но, как советуют, невредно прочитать и человеческим языком: Число одинарной точности по IEEE, оно же, обычно, float
P.P.P.S.
Извините, исправил опечатку, код был с округлением до 4-х цифр, если нужны просто первые 4 цифры, т.е. в результате ближайшее к 0.6666, то следует использовать trunc(in*10000.)/10000..
